# Connecting to SVN Repo with Custom Port

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2013, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, ankhsvn

For a school project I'm trying to connect to an svn repo hosted in the computing department. I've tried connecting to it using VisualSVN, AnkhSVN, and SlikSVN and none of them will connect. I was given a URL like `svn+ssh://username@domain.edu/path/to/repo` and a custom port (let's say 5598).

I've looked around for a way to specify a port number on all 3 clients and found nothing, so I specified it in the URL (`svn+ssh://username@domain.edu:5598/path/to/repo`) and all 3 report errors. With Slik SVN I tried using `svn checkout <URL without username> --username username --password password <local path>` and it still fails.

Slik SVN reports e210004: malformed network data;
AnkhSVN just fails to connect without me being able to see an error;
VisualSVN says the connection timed out.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Edit: formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it. I found documentation for VisualSVN for using svn+ssh. It is located [here](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00008/) and involved editing the SVN config file. From there I was able to specify additional options (`-P 5598`). That didn't completely fix the issue, because the Repo Browser wouldn't accept the password I gave it when it asked. To fix that, I added another option `-pw password` and I can finally browse the repo. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed [documentation](https://www.csoft.net/docs/svn.html.en).

TortoiseSVN is recommended.

Comment: Using the information there, I use TortoiseSVN and it says it can't create tunnel.